# How to change files with a specific word to end in.fasta in linux

Tags: linux, filenames, fasta

How do I select and change files that have a specific word in it to all end in ".fasta"?

For example
I'm selecting files with the word "car" in it.

```
find /home/user -name "*car*"
```

which gives me

```
/home/user/car.txt
/home/user/scar.fa
/home/user/cart.fa
/home/user/scart.fasta
```

but I dont how to change them so they all end in ".fasta"

SO the end result would be

```
/home/user/car.fasta
/home/user/scar.fasta
/home/user/cart.fasta
/home/user/scart.fasta
```

Comment: Um... "\*.car\*.fasta*" (This should have been asked at [unix.se] or [su] instead, BTW. It's a basic OS question and not a programming question.)

Comment: sorry about posting it at the wrong place, i'm new to this.  thanks for the tip

Comment: Do you mean, how to change the find query, or how to rename files?

Comment: how to rename files. Since in my example all files with the word "car" in it has different file extensions, so I wanted to change it so they all ended in ".fasta"

Answer (score 0):

To rename all files that contain the substring `car`, have an extension, but not the `.fasta` extension:

```
find . ! -name "*.fasta" -name "*car*.*" -execdir sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.*}.fasta"' _ {} \;
```

For `find` to `exec`ute the short `sh` script (in file's `dir`), both conditions have to be satisfied: file name must not end with `.fasta` and file name must contain `car`. The `find` will execute the `sh` script for each file matched, providing the file name via placeholder `{}` as the first positional argument to the script.

In the script, we use [shell parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) to strip any extension ([`${var%pat}`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#from_the_end)) and replace it with `.fasta`.

Comment: For some reason I get an error saying                                                       
           'mv: cannot stat `': No such file or directory'

Comment: Check the edited version. Now it makes sure the file *has* an extension before stripping it.

Comment: @Maurice, any luck with this solution?